# Android image matrix and limit boundaries misbehavior

Tags: android, image, scaling, multi-touch

I have a problem regarding Image Scaling and Dragging in Android. I created my own view. A part of the view is a image, which is zoom- and draggable. As long as this part of the image is as big as the whole view, everything works fine. The image zooms and drags perfectly and the limiting also works great. But when I try to fill only a part of the view with the bitmap, my limiting on the right bottom side of the image breaks. The more the image is scaled, the more redundant offset I have in the bottom right corner.

The matrix need to be independent of the screen and view size because the user can save the view´s matrix. To make the matrix independent I declared a value getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT, which is the size of the image. The whole view´s size is declared in getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_HEIGHT / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_WIDTH. As a result the ratio of the view is always the same even if the view is disformed.

I think the reason is the postrescaling/translating of the image. On the other hand the matrix is not changed by the ondraw method. It makes a copy and than retranslate and rezoom the image in the innerpart of the view.

Here to Images to demonstrate the issue:

[View at Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIvll.png)

[When user drags or zoom the image on the bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apN2Q.png)

The Source Code:

setContent:

```
private float           minScale;
private float           PIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH;
private float           PIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT;

public void setContent(FailPictureInfoContainer ic, Bitmap bm) {
    if (ic == null)
        return;

    ic.text[0] = (ic.text[0] != null) ? ic.text[0] : "";
    ic.text[1] = (ic.text[1] != null) ? ic.text[1] : "";
    bitmap = bm;

    //CREATE MATRIX
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    float[] matrixAsFloats = new float[9];
    if (bitmap != null) {//Wenn Bild vorhanden und noch ohne Matrix, angepasste Matrix erzeugen.

        //Wenn breiter als hoch
        if (getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH()/bm.getWidth() < getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT()/bm.getHeight())
            m.postScale(getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT() / bm.getHeight(), getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT() / bm.getHeight());

        //Wenn höher als breit
        else
            m.postScale(getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH() / bm.getWidth(), getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH() / bm.getWidth());
    }
    m.getValues(matrixAsFloats);
    setMinScale((matrixAsFloats[Matrix.MSCALE_X]>matrixAsFloats[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]) ? matrixAsFloats[Matrix.MSCALE_X] : matrixAsFloats[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);

    if (ic.matrix == null)
        ic.matrix = matrixAsFloats;

    this.ic = ic;
    update();
}
```

drawOnCanvas:

```
    @Override
void drawOnCanvas(Canvas canvas, float width, float height) {
    if (bitmap == null || matrix_pixel_independent == null || ic == null)
        return;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIc().matrix));
    // TopText & BottomText ANGLEICHEN
    TextPaint_TOP = getFormattedTextView((int) (ic.textsize[0] * width / getPIXEL_OUTPUT_WIDTH()), ic.color[0]);
    TextPaint_BOTTOM = getFormattedTextView((int) (ic.textsize[1] * width / getPIXEL_OUTPUT_WIDTH()), ic.color[1]);

    // Canvas anpassen.
    canvas.setDensity(bitmap.getDensity());
    matrix_pixel_dependent.set(matrix_pixel_independent);
    float borderPadding = 7f * width / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_WIDTH(); //Abstand zwischen Linie und Bild.
    float paddingFactor = (getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_WIDTH() - getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH()) / 2 * width
            / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_WIDTH(); //Abstand zwischen View und Bild.
    float lowerBound = getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT() * height / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_HEIGHT() + paddingFactor + borderPadding; // Entspricht y-Wert unter Bild und Padding.
    matrix_pixel_dependent.preScale(width / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_WIDTH(), height / getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_HEIGHT(), 0,0);
    matrix_pixel_dependent.postTranslate(paddingFactor, paddingFactor);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix_pixel_dependent, paint);
    paint.setColorFilter(null);
            }
```

onTouchEvent:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (bitmap == null || getIc() == null)
        return true;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //DOUBLE TAP
            lastTapped = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapped;
            if (lastTapped < 350 && lastTapped > 90){
                touchEnabled = !touchEnabled;
                lastTapped = System.currentTimeMillis()-900;
            }else
                lastTapped = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (!touchEnabled) {
                invalidate();
                return false;
            }

            //MOVE PREPARE
            savedMatrix.set(matrix_pixel_independent);
            Finger_startPosition.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            Finger_oldDistance = spacing(event);
            if (Finger_oldDistance > 3f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix_pixel_independent);
                midPoint(Finger_Midpoint, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            mode = NONE;

            if (posChanged) {
                posChanged = false;

                if (getIc().matrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X] < getMinScale()) {
                    float scale = getMinScale() / getIc().matrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                    matrix_pixel_independent.preScale(scale, scale, Finger_Midpoint.x, Finger_Midpoint.y);
                }

                matrix_pixel_independent.getValues(getIc().matrix);

                float newX_post = 0;
                float newY_post = 0;
                float imageWidth_post = newX_post + bitmap.getWidth() * getIc().matrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                float imageHeight_post = newY_post + bitmap.getHeight() * getIc().matrix[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
                RectF drawingRect_post = new RectF(getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_X], getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_Y],
                        getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + imageWidth_post, getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + imageHeight_post);
                float diffUp_post = Math.min(getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT() - drawingRect_post.bottom, -drawingRect_post.top);
                float diffDown_post = Math.max(getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_HEIGHT() - drawingRect_post.bottom, -drawingRect_post.top);
                float diffLeft_post = Math.min(getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH() - drawingRect_post.right, -drawingRect_post.left);
                float diffRight_post = Math.max(getPIXEL_INDEPENDENT_INNER_WIDTH() - drawingRect_post.right, -drawingRect_post.left);

                if (diffUp_post > 0)
                    newY_post += diffUp_post;

                if (diffDown_post < 0)
                    newY_post += diffDown_post;

                if (diffLeft_post > 0)
                    newX_post += diffLeft_post;

                if (diffRight_post < 0)
                    newX_post += diffRight_post;

                matrix_pixel_independent.postTranslate(newX_post, newY_post);


                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "width: "+imageWidth_post+" height: "+imageHeight_post+ " xstart: "+getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_X]+ " ystart: " +getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]+ " xend: "+ getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + imageWidth_post+" yend: "+getIc().matrix[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + imageHeight_post);

                //Listener anstupsen.
                if (OnMeGustaViewChangedListener != null)
                    OnMeGustaViewChangedListener.onViewChanged();

                matrix_pixel_independent.getValues(getIc().matrix);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            matrix_pixel_independent.set(savedMatrix);
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                //DRAGGING
                float eventX = event.getX() - Finger_startPosition.x;
                float eventY = event.getY() - Finger_startPosition.y;
                matrix_pixel_independent.postTranslate(eventX, eventY);

                //Position hat sich geändert -> Listener.
                posChanged = eventX != 0 || eventY != 0;
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                //ZOOMING
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 3f) {
                    float scale = newDist / Finger_oldDistance;
                    matrix_pixel_independent.postScale(scale, scale, Finger_Midpoint.x, Finger_Midpoint.y);

                    //Position hat sich geändert -> Listener.
                    posChanged = true;
                }
            }
            matrix_pixel_independent.getValues(getIc().matrix);
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Spacing between Fingers on event.
 * 
 * @param event
 * @return
 */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/**
 * MidPoint between Fingers on event.
 * 
 * @param point
 * @param event
 */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

Try to get it solved for days, please help me! Would be so thankful!